# Can't find mega stones

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have upgraded my mega ring, it's 8:15 and I can't find any mega stones. Is this a glitch? Will i have to restart my game, or buy a new one maybe? I've tried finding all of the stones on many occasions but to no avail. I'VE ALREADY UPGRADED MY MEGA RING AND ITS AFTER 8 AND BEFORE 9. Why is this happening?

Comment: What mega stone are you trying to get? What version of pokemon do you have (X or Y)? And where are you finding them?

Comment: I have x, im trying to get gyrados and kangaskahns mega stones and im looking in their supposed location between 8 and 9 and their not there